# google maps example - marker show/hide not reflected on the map immediately

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm debugging vanilla example from google website:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove#try-it-yourself

JSFiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/esxq8agk/

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVwSE.jpg

Now I set 2 breakpoints:

```
'setMapOnAll(null)' line 108 

'setMapOnAll(map)' line 113
```

Then I start debugging using Google Chrome menu -> More tools -> Developer Tools. On 'Hide Markers' click and 'Step over next function call' changes on the map are reflected immediately - red marker disappears from the map.

On 'Show Markers' click and 'Step over next function call' nothing happens. I can keep clicking 'Step over next function all' for a good while and still nothing happens. Red marker only shows back up when I click 'Resume script execution'.

Is that a bug? Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Is the issue only with the debugger?  The fiddle seems to work OK for me otherwise, so I doubt it is a bug in the API.

Comment: The main issue is that in my application I have many different sets of markers that I want to show/hide. Because of explained behavior when I change between two sets of markers - everything blinks. Even though I do first 'show new markers' then later 'hide old markers' - old markers get hidden/removed from the map earlier. 
I asked another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181450/google-maps-javascript-markers-blink-on-refresh

Comment: Do the markers have different icons?  Can you move the ones that are on the map  (rather than hiding them all, then adding new ones)?

Comment: This problem occurs even if all markers have the same standard red google icon. In my case all sets of markers are separate from each other and have different number of markers. There is no simple way of moving them.
I recorded a video here: https://vimeo.com/288317890

Comment: @geocodezip I created another JSFiddle to show how they blink when switching between two sets:
https://jsfiddle.net/esxq8agk/24/
Use 'Show Old Markers' and 'Show New Markers' to see how all of them blink on switch.

Comment: For reference, I also reported the bug on google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114705284

Answer (score 0):

This question is not getting any traction nor positive feedback. I managed to hack it to make it work for me anyway. Simply added delay between executing

```
setMapOnAll(map)
```

and

```
setMapOnAll(null)
```

Below is JSFiddle and the code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/esxq8agk/28/

```
function removeNews() {
  setMapOnAll(newMarkers, null);
}

function showNew() {
  setMapOnAll(newMarkers, map);
  setTimeout(removeOlds, 50);
}

function removeOlds() {
  setMapOnAll(oldMarkers, null);
}
function showOld() {
  setMapOnAll(oldMarkers, map);
  setTimeout(removeNews, 50);
}

function setMapOnAll(set, map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
    set[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```